# re-enter a class every render in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

i have created an animation in a class and i want the animation to apply every render.

here is the js file:

```
render(){
   return(
     <div>
        <div className="slide">some data</div>
     </div>
   )
}
```

the css file:

```
.slide{
   animation:an 1s;
}
@keyframes an{
  0%{color:red}
  100%{color:blue}
}
```

but the animation happens only at the first render.
how can i apply the animation every render?

Comment: Since react won't re-render the element unless it has to you can't expect the element to get inserted into the page every render, so you would need to add and then remove a class once the animation has finished for example

Comment: @alejandroFernandez What exactly are you trying to achieve with the "render"? If you want the animation to "render" on a specific action, simply use the jQuery inbuilt `EventListener` and use the `addClass()` method to "add the animation to the rendered object." Seems like a far more elegant solution than rendering each individual div element.

Comment: Or you can make the animation infinite: `animation:an 1s infinite;`